# Why is du command showing incorrect results

Tags: linux

The below output showing 21GB files each.

```
[root@myhost data]# ls -l
total 100092
-rw-rw---- 1 ora4 ora4 **22548586496** Dec 18 21:09 temp01.dbf
-rw-rw---- 1 ora4 ora4 **22548586496** Dec 18 19:38 temp02.dbf
```

But when i used du command, its shows only 49MB.

```
[root@myhost data]# du -sh *
49M     temp01.dbf
49M     temp02.dbf
```

Could you please let me know, how to correct the values.

Comment: The results are both correct. These are [sparse files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file); they are 21 GB long, but use 49 MB of disk space.

Comment: So, does the df output also showing 2% utilization.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

execute the `ls -lh` `ls -l`. will display the size in the bytes. du -sh in du command you are mentioning the h for displaying the result in human readable format. If you check with the du it will display the output in kb(kilo bytes). Compare the results with `ls -lh` and `du -sh *`.